# Web api result updating model but not view in angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am calling Web-Api from angular-service and that returning data to my angular-controller. 
$scope.$watch showing correct data, but view is not changing related data.

My Angularjs-Service is,

BDayModule.service("serviceUser", function ($http) {

```
this.getData = function () {
    return $http.get('/Users/listAll').then(function (success) {
        console.log("success.data 1 = " + success.data);
        return success.data;
    },
    function (error) {
        alert("Insertion fail");
    },
    function (process) {

    });

};
```

});

My angularjs-controller is,

BDayModule.controller("ControllerUsers", function ($scope, $interval, serviceUser, commonFunction) {

```
$scope.allBDayData = [];
$scope.getAllUsers = function () {

    var myDataPromise = serviceUser.getData();
    myDataPromise.then(function (result) {
        console.log("success.data 2 = " + result);
        $scope.allBDayData = result;

        $scope.$watch('allBDayData',
            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log('allBDayData Changed');
                console.log(newValue);
                console.log(oldValue);
            });
    });


}
```

});

## My view,

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerUsers">

<input type="button" value="Show all" ng-click="getAllUsers()" />

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <caption>
            <span class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Search.$" placeholder="Full filter" /></span>
        </caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Name : &nbsp; <input type="text" ng-model="Search.UserName" placeholder="Filter" /></th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Birth Date</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in allBDayData | filter: Search">
                <td>{{data.UserName}}</td>
                <td>{{data.EmailId}}</td>
                <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.BirthDate}}</td>
                <td>{{data.Age}}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" style="width: 90px;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Button on which I click is in master page,

```
<li><a ng-controller="ControllerUsers" href="#list" ng-click="getAllUsers()"> Show All </a>
```

this button rendering page correctly based on routing, and firing getAllUsers() too. but not changing my view result...

Comment: It is rendering data fine when I click on button which is on same view, So service returning correct data format , but I want to make work same thing when I click on master page button.
Both are returning same data on console.
and I tried to use $scope.$apply, but its giving me error : $digest already in work.

Comment: No need for the digest, just create a plnkr for the code on plnkr website.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER and ASP.NET MVC... So
Just for code review purpose I added it on plnkr...
Please refer it...

http://plnkr.co/edit/GejNvIHwzvr25OZBjpTV?p=preview

Comment: My API call is returning result before page is rendering...
But that should not be the reason for not rendering data on view... r8 ?

Comment: One of the problems that your code has is that your scripts are all in the head section and this will slow your page render/load, also I don't get how do you inject listAll.cshtml template ?

Comment: You can see the _Layout.cshtml page...
I put 1 link there, which open listAll.cshtml as defined routing in Module.js